# Specify decimal places for currency in FORMAT call

Tags: sql-server, globalization

My database contains fuel unit prices which typically end with a fractional penny value, such as $2.099 per gallon. I use the built-in `FORMAT` call in order to specify the locale. This doesn't allow me to use currency formatting with more than 2 decimal places. Is there a way to override this? Or am I stuck doing some custom formatting based on many many possible locales?

Consider this example:

```
DECLARE @fuelPrice FLOAT = 2.099
SELECT FORMAT(@fuelPrice, 'G', 'en-US') AS 'NoDollarSign'
      ,FORMAT(@fuelPrice, 'C', 'en-US') AS 'WrongDecimalPlaces'
      ,'$2.099' as 'WhatIWant'
```

which outputs:

```
NoDollarSign    WrongDecimalPlaces  WhatIWant
2.099           $2.10               $2.099
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) allow you to specify a precision. Use `C3` as the format instead:

```
DECLARE @fuelPrice FLOAT = 2.099
SELECT FORMAT(@fuelPrice, 'C3', 'en-US')
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can just do this, if the only reason you're doing this is for display purposes?

```
DECLARE @fuelPrice FLOAT = 2.099
SELECT '$' + cast(@fuelprice as varchar(10))
```

Comment: In my actual code, the locale isn't always `en-US` so hard-coding a `$` isn't an option. It would need to reflect the locale's currency symbol, which is sometimes shown after the decimal value.